# How to draw a dotted spirograph using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My code is working until some point and then it's spiraling at one place. Tried debugging it but it's not helping.

Current Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNOqu.png)
Expected Output: Something like this instead of the dash...I am using dots
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yct3r.png)

```
from turtle import Turtle, done
from math import pi, copysign

chinky = Turtle()
colours = ["DeepPink2", "DarkTurquoise", "chartreuse3", "CornflowerBlue"]
j = 0


def draw_spirograph(size_of_gap, radius):
    global j
    for i in range(int(360 / size_of_gap)):
        chinky.color(colours[j])
        if j < 3:
            j += 1
        else:
            j = 0
        draw_dotted_circle(radius, 5)
        chinky.setheading(chinky.heading() + size_of_gap)


def draw_dotted_circle(radius, dot_size):
    chinky.penup()
    chinky.sety(radius)

    diameter = 2 * radius
    circumference = pi * diameter
    dot_extent = 360 * dot_size / circumference  # diameter to angle

    times_y_crossed = 0
    x_sign = 1

    while times_y_crossed < 2:
        chinky.dot(dot_size)  # draw the dot
        chinky.right(dot_extent)
        chinky.forward(dot_size)

        chinky.right(dot_extent)  # draw the gap
        chinky.forward(dot_size)

        x_sign_new = copysign(1, chinky.xcor())

        if x_sign_new != x_sign:
            times_y_crossed += 1
            x_sign = x_sign_new

    chinky.pendown()


chinky.speed("fastest")
draw_spirograph(5, 100)
done()
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Maybe there are some environment specific things?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with segments by creating a custom circle function that will draw a segmented circle with alternating colors.  Moving the turtle at angles allows you to draw the segments without having to do any trigonometry.

```
import turtle as tg

def segCircle(x,y,radius,step):
    colors = ["DeepPink2", "DarkTurquoise", "chartreuse3", "CornflowerBlue"]
    c      = 0                   # color index
    prev   = None                # start of segment
    for a in range(0,360,step):  # run through segment points
        tg.penup()
        tg.goto(x,y)             # center of circle
        tg.setheading(a)         # segment point angle
        tg.forward(radius)       # move to perimeter
        if prev:
            tg.pendown()         # draw line from previous segment point
            tg.color(colors[0])
            colors.append(colors.pop(0)) # rotate colors
            tg.goto(*prev)
            prev = None
        else:
            prev = tg.pos()     # skip every other point
```

Drawing the spirograph:

```
wn = tg.Screen() # setup for "instantaneous drawing"
wn.tracer(0) 

angle  = 10
radius = 100

for a in range(0,360,angle):       # offset circles around center
    tg.penup() 
    tg.goto(0,0)                   # move to origin
    tg.setheading(a)               # set offsetted angle
    tg.forward(radius)             # go to center of circle
    segCircle(*tg.pos(),radius,angle//2) # draw it


wn.update()    # render drawing in one paint
wn.mainloop()
```